# How can i use custom serialize method in Flink?

Tags: serialization, apache-flink

I use `AtomicLongMap` in the construct function of RichMapFunctin.Like

```
public class PathAnalysis extends RichMapFunction<ApiLog, ApiLog> {

private final AtomicLongMap<Object> mObjectAtomicLongMap;

public PathAnalysis()
{
    mObjectAtomicLongMap = AtomicLongMap.create();
}
}
```

register the custom serizlize class, but it not work

```
env.getConfig().registerTypeWithKryoSerializer(AtomicLongMap.class, new AtomicLongMapSerializer());
```

It cause:

```
org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: The implementation of the RichMapFunction is not serializable. The object probably contains or references non serializable fields.
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:99)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.clean(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1550)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.clean(DataStream.java:184)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.map(DataStream.java:528)
    at com.ghzs.Topology.main(Topology.java:91)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.flink.shaded.curator.org.apache.curator.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AtomicLongMap
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.serializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:315)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:81)
    ... 4 more
```

`AtomicLongMap` is not implements of `Serializable` .How can I register a effective custom serialize method?

Comment: Is that problem I use the object in construct?

Answer (score 2):

Mark AtomicLongMap as transient, and allocate it in the open() call that your function will receive (because it's a RichMapFunction). So something like:

```
public class PathAnalysis extends RichMapFunction<ApiLog, ApiLog> {

  private transient AtomicLongMap<Object> mObjectAtomicLongMap;

  public PathAnalysis() { }

  @Override
  public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
    super.open(parameters);

    mObjectAtomicLongMap = AtomicLongMap.create();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with implementation of this function like:

```
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.RichMapFunction;
    import com.google.common.util.concurrent.AtomicLongMap;
    public class PathAnalysis extends RichMapFunction<ApiLog, ApiLog> {
    private final AtomicLongMap<Object> mObjectAtomicLongMap;

    public PathAnalysis()
    {
      mObjectAtomicLongMap = AtomicLongMap.create();
    }

    @Override
    public ApiLog map(ApiLog value) throws Exception {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
    }
    }
```